# Get Current Command In Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I'm creating a shell script that will always read the user's current commands from the shell.

I'm currently using the `read` command which I'm not satisfied with since it is used for prompting questions. Example:

```
root@hostname: ./script.sh
Question here?
answer - `read` command
```

I want the my script to be invoked when the user directly inputs a command on the command line (the script is already running through /etc/profile.d/myapp.sh once logged in).

```
root@hostname: read the command here
result will happen
```

My example script `myapp.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "input" = "value"]
then
    do some actions
fi
```

Comment: Do you know about the `source` and `eval` builtins of your `bash` shell?

Comment: no... sorry for lack of knowledge

Comment: Read http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: great reference :) thank u very much!

Comment: Are you trying to make things easier for the user (consider a menu) or making it more secure (I will start a vi, escape to a shell and I will be out of your control) ? Or just logging (see history file or use `script`) ?

Comment: Trying to develop a script with that function. And yes like for security as well and for further other ideas to develop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are explicitly targeting Bash, I would recommend setting up Bash aliases for those commands.

At the start of the user's session, your program can run the following commands to create bash aliases:

```
alias command1="/your/path/script.sh command1"
alias command2="/your/path/script.sh command2"
```

Then for instance when the user enters `command1`, it will expand and run `/your/path/script.sh command1` instead.

Comment: i change command1 into `sudo -s` i receive `-bash: alias: sudo not found`. i want is when a user type a sudo -s command a follow up question will proceed

Comment: @BLNK I wouldn't recommend doing the following, but it might be a starting off point: You could change `command1` into `sudo` instead of `sudo -s`. So for instance: `alias sudo="/your/path/script.sh"`. Then you could catch the `-s` argument in your program. It seems like a very bad idea to override the system `sudo` command though - it will probably end up breaking stuff at best, and compromising system security at the worst - so why not choose a custom command for your program, sort of like `mysudo`?

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible then since it is an open source software otherwise you mentioned is best in practice since it is a built-in security command. Thanks!

Comment: It is already working. Thanks! Normal users can't use the `sudo` command easily :)

Comment: follow up question if it is ok.since i ran the program and whatever command i do with the `sudo` it will ran the pointed sh file. But how can it catch if it has the `-s` as you also mentioned?

Comment: @BLNK This post may help as far as parsing command line arguments such as `-s`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash